# Adding values to Data frame and Export

Tags: python, dataframe, tokenize

I am trying to add two values as a list in Data Frame 
one is the Sentence and other once is the List of words I got, after tokenization of those sentences

for now, I have done the following code

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
example = ['Mary had a little lamb' , 
        'Jack went up the hill' , 
        'Jill followed suit' ,    
        'i woke up suddenly' ,
       'it was a really bad dream...']


def hi():
    for i in example:
        #print (word_tokenize(i),i)
        a=[i,word_tokenize(i)]

        print(a)
```

The expected output would be

Data Frame having two columns, Original Sentence and Tokens of that sentence

Example

**Orignal Sentence | Tokens**

My name is max     |  my,name,is,max

This is windows     | This, is , windows

Comment: Why does this involve pandas? You won't get any benefits of the library by storing lists in cells

Comment: is there any other way do it , so that i get two columns one is for sentence and other is for tokens ?

Comment: By using a regular python dictionary. It's hard to say without knowing what you intend to do afterwards, but the dataframe is not usually a good option for storing this kind of data

Comment: Can please you show me how ?

Comment: `my_dict = {sentence: word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in example}`

Comment: Actually i intend to save those in some database. So that i know which documents and their corresponding sentence

Comment: Ok, and there's nothing stopping you from doing that. I gave you a direct mapping that can be saved to a database.

Comment: Thanks A lot , really appreciates the help and guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Original Sentence'] = a[0]  
df['Tokens'] = a[1]
```

Or we can skip your function entirely:

```
df['Original Sentence'] = example
df['Tokens'] = [word_tokenize(i) for i in example]
```

EDIT:
Since it appears you do not have a dataframe to begin with.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Original Sentence': example,
                   'Tokens': [word_tokenize(i) for i in example]})
print(df) #to see your dataframe 
df.to_csv('mydata.csv') #To output your dataframe into a csv file
```

Other format:

```
df.to_sql(etc...) #Refer to comment below
```

To output as a sql direct to your database, setup specific to your db is required. Refer here for example:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: It shows me one warning before compilation 
un defined name 'df'

and an error 
"Length of values does not match length of index"

Comment: the second solution also gives an error  "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: Editing on a phone is no fun at all :/ you need a closing `}`. I fixed the list comp and destroyed the dictionary and now my edits don't seem to be holding sorry

Comment: Thanks , Can you show me how to remove stop words from the original sentences?

Comment: What are the stop words? @adnan

Comment: stop words https://www.ranks.nl/stopwords  example (a.an,the.she , he etc)

Comment: @adnan You can actually put the stopwords into a `list` or `set`, and then do a removal `if word not in stopwords: ...` Remove the stopwords from your words in a sentence via `sentence.split(' ')`, then do a `' '.join(words)` to get back your sentence